# How to fix MySqlCommand AddWithValue() Not Assigning Parameters

Tags: c#, mysql

Want to send a Select MySqlCommand query but the AddWithValue() method doesn't assign given parameters their values. Therefor I'm unable to get the right data from database.

I've already tried changing @ symbol to ?
I've also tried Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", textbox1.text);
I removed all the unnecessary apostrophes. 
I tried to prepare the command before and after assigning parameters.

```
#define debug

Database_Interface db = new Database_Handler();

        public string GetIDFromDB(string user)
        {

            using(MySqlConnection conn = db.Connection)
            {
                db.OpenConnection(conn);
                string sql = "SELECT ID FROM Users WHERE USERNAME = @User";
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql,conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", user);
                    cmd.Prepare();
#if debug
                    return cmd.CommandText;
#endif
                    MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    db.Connection.Close();
                    if (rdr.HasRows)
                    {
                        rdr.Read();
                        return rdr.GetString("ID");
                    }
                    else
                        return "inv_user";
                }
            }
        }
```

What the debug return, returns is the same sql with no params actually assigned. However when I've tried to do it the very basic way put the user var inside the sql it works as it should. The only problem is with AddWithValue().

Comment: This whole thing would be a one-liner if you were using Dapper or EF.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that adding a parameter is actually going to modify the `CommandText` by replacing "@User" with the value you specify. That is not the case. What actually happens is the whole command is sent to the database with the query text and the parameter values separate. It's the database that actually does the substitution and, even then, it never changes the text of the query. The query text is parsed and a set of steps carried out to perform what it says and one of those steps is setting a variable to the parameter value.

Comment: By the way, if it is your intention to get a single value then don't use a data reader. `ExecuteScalar` exists specifically for that purpose.

Comment: What is the error message you get from MySQL when you try to run your code? Or do you just get an empty result set with now rows found?

Comment: Aight, thank you guys for tips. Will try out the `ExecuteScalar` didn't know about that function. As of what error message I get, none. The database just returns empty. Even though it shouldn't be. Because using the common way, substituting the name manually returns exactly what I want, it seems like the database returns a false null only when using parameters.